# gst-launch command to play a video using vaapi hardware acceleration

Tags: gstreamer, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I need two gst-launch-1.0 command lines

1) The first one is simple to play a video (.mp4) without using any hardware acceleration.

2) The sencond one is to play the video (.mp4) using hardware acceleration, I am using Intel HD graphics with the i965 driver.

I already installed the gstreamer plugins.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you specifically want to choose decoders yourself, I would recommend playbin and decodebin for playback.

Comment: It'd be neat if GStreamer added a hints feature to playbin|decodebin.  Or maybe a demuxbin.  There are unfortunately many instances where certain encoded outputs simply won't make it correctly through a given decoder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1: using libav

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=[FILENAME] ! qtdemux ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

2: using vaapi

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=[FILENAME] ! qtdemux ! vaapih264dec ! vaapisink
```